# How to stop createing duplicate div while creating div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am creating a button and progressbar in **techsubj div**, but i can create multiple buttons and sub div unber  **techsubj div**, what can i do to avoid this

***HTML***

```
<div class="row" id="addsubj">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><a id="newsubj" onclick="addnewsubj()" class="btn btn-info">+</a></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <div class="progress">
        <input type="text" id="subjname" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function addnewsubj(){
var a = document.getElementById("subjname").value;
if(!a==""){
    $('.techsubj').append(
    '<div class="row" id="'+ a +'">'+
        '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">'+
            '<a href="#fourth" id="'+ a +'" class="btn btn-info" >'+ a +'</a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">'+
            '<div class="progress">'+
                '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">'+
                    '<span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'
    );
}
else{
    alert("Text Box is empty");
}}
```

Comment: when i am trying to create a div via taking name from textbox, then how should i stop creating it duplicate div. i am setting div ID by taking text from text box so, when i insert text and press button them if that div is already created then it should give alert to choose different name for that div ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if( $('.row').length < 2 ){

// create dynamic div

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add one more if condition there to check if the `.row` is available there or not:

```
if(a!=""){

   if($('.techsubj').find('.row').length == 0){

       // put the append here

   }

}
```

---

I think this would be better:

```
if(a!="" && $('.techsubj').find('.row').length == 0){

       // put the append here    
}
```

one more suggestion is this instead of this check `if(!a==""){` do this: `if(a!=""){`

Answer (score 0):

Use proper conditioning  if(a!="") ,And it will be solved ,Its ok,I tested on My side

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Dz73A/

```
function addnewsubj(){
var a = $("#subjname").val();
if( a != "" && $('.techsubj').children().length==0 ){
$('.techsubj').append(
    '<div class="row" id="'+ a +'">'+
        '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">'+
            '<a href="#fourth" id="'+ a +'" class="btn btn-info" >'+ a +'</a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">'+
            '<div class="progress">'+
                '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">'+
                    '<span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'
    );
}
else{
    alert("Text Box is empty");
}}

$("#add").click(addnewsubj);
```

Comment: in this example i am unable to create another div with different name also

Comment: That's was what you asked, is't it? It blocks creation of multiple divs. Sorry if i've misunderstood you.

Comment: sorry if i am unable to explain. on button creation i want to create a **main div** in which there are two columns  in col one there is a button , in col two there is progressbar. with this i am setting textbox value as button name and main div's id, so how should create the div hows id is matching with already created div